# Outer join using Cube.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cube.js

I am using Cube.js for fetching the data from Postgres. By default, cube.js does a left join on 2 selected tables. Is there any way to get the result by Full Outer Join?

User Register Table 
ID  TIME 
1   10.00
3   9.00

Last Active Table
ID  TIME
1   11.00
2   10.00

So output I want is
ID  Last_active_time  Register_time
1   11.00               10.00
2   10.00               ----
3   ----                9.00

Comment: Could you please provide what data structure you have and what's your final result you want to get?

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cube.js uses only `LEFT JOIN` to express relationship between cubes for the purpose of encouraging right Cube.js schema design: https://cube.dev/docs/joins. Your case can be expressed as following Cube.js schema:

```
cube(`Users`, {
  sql: `
  SELECT DISTINCT id FROM users_register 
  UNION 
  SELECT DISTINCT id FROM last_active`,

  joins: {
    UsersRegister: {
      sql: `${Users}.id = ${UsersRegister}.id`,
      relationship: `hasMany`
    },
    UsersLastActive: {
      sql: `${Users}.id = ${UsersLastActive}.id`,
      relationship: `hasMany`
    }
  },

  dimensions: {
    id: {
      sql: `id`,
      type: `number`,
      primaryKey: true
    }
  }
});

cube(`UsersRegister`, {
  sql: `select * from users_register`,

  measures: {
    registerTime: {
      sql: `time`,
      type: `min`
    }
  },

  dimensions: {
    id: {
      sql: `id`, // if id is unique within users_register
      type: `number`,
      primaryKey: true
    }
  }
});

cube(`UsersLastActive`, {
  sql: `select * from last_active`,

  measures: {
    lastActiveTime: {
      sql: `time`,
      type: `max`
    }
  },

  dimensions: {
    id: {
      sql: `id`, // if id is unique within last_active
      type: `number`,
      primaryKey: true
    }
  }
});
```

Query to get desired result:

```
{
  measures: ['UsersLastActive.lastActiveTime', 'UsersRegister.registerTime'],
  dimensions: ['Users.id']
}
```